# Relacionamento de 1 atributo com tabelas diferentes

Tags: mysql, tabela-html, entidade-relacionamento

Galera, boa tarde.

Estou Modelando meu Banco de Dados (MySQL) e surgiu uma dúvida. 
No banco, entre outra, tenho as seguintes tabelas:
**Funcionarios - Setores - Filiais**

Um Funcionário trabalha OU em um Setor da sede OU em uma Filial. Eu queria criar um relacionamento entre um atributo (*local_de_trabalho*) da tabela **Funcionario** com os códigos (*id*) da tabela **Setor** OU da tabela **Unidade**.

Isso é possível? Como faria?

Comment: Você colocou `OU`, mas só para desencargo de dúvida, um funcionário pode ter SEDE e FILIAL ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 1):

Segue um simples exemplo que acabei de criar tendo em vista sua questão. Segue imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observando o exemplo creio que vc possa criar uma de acordo com suas necessidades.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que o campo *local_de_trabalho* está relacionado a uma **ou** outra table, não é possível tratá-lo como uma foreign key, o que você pode fazer, nesse caso, é ter um outro campo (ex: *tipo_local_de_trabalho*) indicando a qual tabela o campo *local_de_trabalho* está sendo relacionado